# Installing Collabnet subversion forces new installation of jdk6

Tags: java, svn, configuration, collabnet

I am trying to install the latest version of Collabnet subversion on my windows server. When i click on the setup icon it comes up with a prompt saying that it needs to to install version 1.6 of the Java runtime environment. It shows that it found version 1.5 on my machine.

I have both version 1.5 and 1.6. How can i make the installation see the 1.6 version without having to install a new version? I checked my %PATH% variable and the path to the 1.6 is included as the first item in the path.

How does it check which version is installed and how can i force it to use the existing 1.6 installation?

Thanks

### Edit

Sorry i forgot to mention i do also have the JAVA_HOME environment already setup and it is pointing at the 1.6 version.

### Edit

I am using Windows server 2003. I tried running java -version from the command line and it returns Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)

The other problem i have is the machine i am installing it to does not have internet access. If i allow Collabnet to go ahead and install the JDK it fails because it cant download it. So im stuck :)

Comment: So, you want to install Subversion Edge...it says this in the README: `" Java 1.6 JRE/JDK must be installed.  The installer will install Java 1.6 if does not detect it as already installed.  The installer will create/replace the JAVA_HOME environment variable so that it points to the Java 1.6 JRE."` Weird! Which version of Windows Server are you using? There is no way to skip it though... http://www.collab.net/nonav/downloads/subversion/readme/csvne_win32win64.html

Comment: Maybe your JRE 1.6.XXX version is older than the JRE 1.6.YYY version the Setup wants to install...

Comment: I am running MS Windows Server 2003 R2. I tried "java -version" from the command prompt and it returns "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)"

Comment: The other problem i have is the machine i am installing it to does not have internet access. If i allow Collabnet to go ahead and install the JDK it fails because it cant download it. So im stuck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i have managed to resolve the problem. It looks like if you are installing the 64bit version of Collabnet Subversion it will complain if it does not find a 64bit JDK.  The versions of JDK i had on my machine were both 32bit JDK.

I installed the 64bit JDK and that resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding **%JAVA_HOME%** environment variable instead of **%PATH%**. After you will have JAVA_HOME added to your system, you can try to install CollabNet Subversion again.

For example, I have following setting of JAVA_HOME variable:

[image]

In case you have set your JAVA_HOME properly, you should be able to choose jdk path during installation.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i do also have the JAVA_HOME environment already setup and it is pointing at the 1.6 version. Thanks